# Безопасны ли Kali, Parrot Security?

Tags: linux, безопасность, kali-linux, parrot

Нашел в одной статье на Хабре интересный комментарий:
[image: при коннекте к сети через networkmanager подбирают первый рабочий конфиг сети]

Где я могу почитать о чем он говорит?(что такое форензика я знаю) Хочу понять о чем он говорит, и как это работает.
Сыллка на [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/337712/)

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm и в целом про то что такое `/dev` GNU/Linux. Про сеть думаю имеется ввиду DHCP профиль Gnome на чем построен  Kali. Не понятно зачем там VPN вообще, автор комента просто стебется. Что вам нужно от "безопасности" инструмента безопасности? Может хочет намекнуть включайте TOR при выходе в сеть, только это не зачем если вам нужно саму сеть изучить к которой подключились и у нее (да не ужели) может и не быть выхода в глобальный Интернет где и есть смысл в TOR и VPN!

Comment: А что на счёт этих конфигов сети? И не понимаю это "при подключении любого устройства через udev+udisks2 его цепляют в rw". Что за rw?

Comment: Read/Write, для /dev/sd0 обычно ro - read only. Советую почитать или пройти курс по базовым аспектам *nix ос.Все недопонимания - отсуствие базовых понятий и терминологии.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте) Parrot Security OS это - дистрибутив GNU / Linux, на основе Debian. Он был создан для того, чтобы выполнять тесты на проникновение (информационная безопасность) для оценки уязвимостей и смягчения последствий их использования, применяется он и в компьютерной криминалистике, а так же способен обеспечить анонимный серфинг в интернете) Можете почитать об ней в этой статье) https://codeby.net/threads/parrot-security-os.57935/